# JSON Recursive looping issue with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, loops

IM having a JSON string like this

```
 [{"group_id":"1","group_name":"coupler system","subgroups":[{"group_id":"9","group_name":"core","subgroups":0},{"group_id":"10","group_name":"dual","subgroups":0}]},{"group_id":"2","group_name":"powersource\/engine","subgroups":[{"group_id":"11","group_name":"petrol","subgroups":[{"group_id":"13","group_name":"ECO-whisper","subgroups":[{"group_id":"15","group_name":"yes","subgroups":0},{"group_id":"16","group_name":"no","subgroups":0}]}]},{"group_id":"12","group_name":"electric","subgroups":[{"group_id":"14","group_name":"mains","subgroups":[{"group_id":"17","group_name":"220V","subgroups":0},{"group_id":"18","group_name":"110V","subgroups":0}]}]}]},{"group_id":"3","group_name":"tool connections","subgroups":[{"group_id":"19","group_name":"1(STO)","subgroups":0},{"group_id":"20","group_name":"2(MTO)","subgroups":0}]},{"group_id":"4","group_name":"oil content","subgroups":[{"group_id":"21","group_name":"2L?","subgroups":0},{"group_id":"22","group_name":"4L?","subgroups":0},{"group_id":"23","group_name":"6L?","subgroups":0}]},{"group_id":"5","group_name":"hose reels","subgroups":[{"group_id":"24","group_name":"no","subgroups":0},{"group_id":"25","group_name":"yes","subgroups":0}]},{"group_id":"6","group_name":"tool support + carry","subgroups":[{"group_id":"29","group_name":"no","subgroups":0},{"group_id":"30","group_name":"yes","subgroups":[{"group_id":"31","group_name":"wheelset","subgroups":[{"group_id":"32","group_name":"yes","subgroups":0},{"group_id":"33","group_name":"no","subgroups":0}]}]}]},{"group_id":"7","group_name":"weight","subgroups":[{"group_id":"34","group_name":"<=15?","subgroups":0},{"group_id":"35","group_name":"<=25?","subgroups":0},{"group_id":"36","group_name":"<=50?","subgroups":0},{"group_id":"37","group_name":"<=100?","subgroups":0}]},{"group_id":"8","group_name":"dimensions","subgroups":[{"group_id":"38","group_name":"SR10","subgroups":0},{"group_id":"39","group_name":"SR20","subgroups":0},{"group_id":"40","group_name":"SR31\/32","subgroups":0},{"group_id":"41","group_name":"SR40","subgroups":0},{"group_id":"42","group_name":"SR41\/42","subgroups":0}]}]
```

I need to use Jquery to make this JSON to the valid HTML table structure as given below,How can i implement it
[image]

This is what i have tried so far..im struck with the recursive looping part

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
           var jsondata = jQuery.parseJSON($.trim($('#groupdata').html())); //the above JSON

           var str = '';
           str +='<table>';
           str +='<tr>';




             for(j=0;j<jsondata.length;j++){



                 str +='<td>'+jsondata[j]['group_name']+'</td>';
        // here i want to call the same loop again if it has subgroups


             }
             str +=' </tr>';
             str+='</table>';
             $('#container').html(str);
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Do not embed JSON in HTML. Just put it directly into the script tags. Or, even better, build that table serverside! Why do you want to do it with JavaScript?

Comment: IM on HTML5 Offline caching ..NO serverside languages !!!

Comment: How should the built markup look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there are three parts to this:

- how to do recursion
- how to build the HTML
- how to do it with jQuery

When you have something like this you need to (a) simplify (b) break it down into its parts. Use simpler data to figure out the recursion and build some HTML. When that is working, introduce a subset of your real data, get that working, and so on.

A rough template.  I'll use this json:

```
var json = '[{ "first": "1", "second": "2", "sub": 0 },{ "first": "3", "second": "4", "sub": [{ "first": "3.1", "second": "3.2", "sub": 0 }] }]';
```

to do recursion you have to break the "row builder" out into a separate function so that it call itself when it needs to.

something like below. You are going to have to work with it for your own data, adjust the html to be what you want etc. The first thing you need to do is understand it.

I don\t pretend this is perfect, and there may be performance improvements to be had, but this should get you headed in the right direction... happy parsing...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var data = $.parseJSON(json);
    var html = "<table>";
    var rows = recurse(data);
    html += rows + "</table>";
    document.write(html);
});

function recurse(data) {
    var row = "";
    for (var e in data) { //each object at this level
        row += "<tr>";
        row += "<td>" + data[e].first + "</td>";
        row += "<td>" + data[e].second + "</td>";
        row += "<td>";
        if (data[e].sub.length == 1) {
            var sub = "<table>";
            sub += recurse(data[e].sub)
            sub += "</table>";
            row += sub;
        }
        row += "</td></tr>";
    }
    return row;
}
```

Comment: Branden's answer above is better in that it uses jQuery and is therefore more concise. If you understand it, its better. If not, the above pure js should help.

Answer (score 4):

You can start by getting rid of that for loop and utilizing the Jquery .each() function. To get you started try something like this. v = value of current node, k = current key

```
$jQuery.each(jsondata, function(k, v) { create(k, v, 0) });

function create(k, v, n) { 
  //print your table the way you want it

  //if the value is an object, loop through each instance of the subcategories
  if(v instanceof Object) {
    $.each(v, function(key, val, n) {
      create(key, val, n+1)
    });
  }
  return;
}
```

You will need to fill in the gaps to make the rows/columns made the way you want them, but this is a template for how to do a recursive call to parse the Object. The n var is used to check what depth the recursion is at if you need such a variable, which I think you might for what your trying to do. n=0 is the top, n=1 would be one level in, n=2 would be two levels in, etc...

Comment: I don't think one would need the recursion level. Just pass the `create` function directly into `each()`

Comment: It might be useful for processing the data, but it was just a suggestion not a requirement, the function will run without the n value.

Answer (score 0):

[Recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29) needs functions. So, build one:

```
function generateTableMarkup(data) {
    for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
        // do something
        if (data[i].subgroups) {
            generateTableMarkup(data[i].subgroups);
        }
    }
}
generateTableMarkup(JSON.parse(...));
```

Comment: if(data[i].subgroups) will not help for this situation because it would always be true. When subgroups is false it still equals 0.

Comment: Huh? The subgroups in the given data are either an array or zero. And zero evaluates to `false` in a boolean condition.